# How to show message in for-loop issues in javascript or using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, for-in-loop

I tried this for almost two days but still nothing. Maybe someone can help who is highly skilled in javascript loops.

I have this code:

```
$(function(){
 var len = $('#groupContainer > div').length;
 var arr = [];
 for(var i=0; i < len; i++){

    var number = $('#number_' + [i + 1]);
    var date = $('#date_' + [i + 1]);
    var count = i + 1;
    var message ="";
    console.log(number)

    var a = number.map(function(){
        return this.value;
    });

    var b = date.map(function(){
        return this.value;
    });

    var newObj = {number: a[0], date: b[0]}
    arr.push(newObj);

}

var message = "";
 for(var c = 0; c < arr.length; c++)
 {        


    for(var d in arr[c])
    {
        message += 'Group: ' + [c + 1] + '\n';
        if(arr[c].hasOwnProperty(d))
        {      
            if(arr[c][d] == "")
            {

                message +=  d + ' is required!\n';
            }

        }
        message = message + "\n";
    }


 }
 alert(message);
});
```

And the expected output:

If all the fields in group 1 is filled and group 2 is not show alertbox:

```
   Group 2:
   Number is required!
   Date is required!
```

If all field is not filled show:

```
   Group 1, 2 Number is required!
   Group 1, 2 Date is required!
```

If all field is filled do nothing.

Here's my **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aldrin27/z4yfohao/12/)**

Comment: So i guess you are doing all of this for validations, right??

Comment: Yes it's for validation purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [code here is too much complicated](http://jsfiddle.net/z4yfohao/15/) and should be simplified.

You need to save the messages in an `object` and loop through them later to show the messages in order.

```
var messages = {};
var message = "";

for(var c = 0; c < arr.length; c++)
{        
    var groupMessage = false;
    for(var d in arr[c])
    {

        if(arr[c].hasOwnProperty(d))
        {      
            if(arr[c][d] == "")
            {
                if(messages[d]==undefined) {
                    messages[d]={groups:[]};
                }
                messages[d].groups.push(c+1);
            }

        }            
    }

    var lastgroup = "";

    for(i in messages) {
      m = messages[i];      
      if(m.groups.join(",")==lastgroup) {
        message = message.replace("Group "+m.groups.join(",")+" ","Group "+m.groups.join(",")+":\n");
        message+=i+" is required!\n";
      }
      else {
          message+="Group "+m.groups.join(",")+" "+i+" is required!\n";
      }
      lastgroup = m.groups.join(",");
    }

  // .....
}
```

Comment: Just one question. Where do I put the message if I want to show Group 1,2 Invalid Date or Group 2 Invalid Date?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
    var len = $('#groupContainer > div').length;
  var arr = [];
    for(var i=0; i < len; i++){

        var number = $('#number_' + [i + 1]);
        var date = $('#date_' + [i + 1]);
        var count = i + 1;
        var message ="";
        var a = number.map(function(){
            return this.value;
        });
        var b = date.map(function(){
            return this.value;
        });
        
        var newObj = {number: a[0], date: b[0]}
  arr.push(newObj);
    }
   console.log(arr);
    var message = "";
    for(var c = 0; c < arr.length; c++)
    {        
        haveErrorInGroup = false;
        for(var d in arr[c])
        {
            if(arr[c].hasOwnProperty(d))
            {      
                if(arr[c][d] == "")
                {
                    if(!haveErrorInGroup){
                        haveErrorInGroup= true;
                       message += 'Group: ' + [c + 1] + '\n';
                    }
                       
                    message +=  d + ' is required!\n';
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
    alert(message);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="groupContainer">
    <div id ="profileGroup1">
        <div class="item">
            Number1: <input type="text" id="number_1" value="20">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
           Date1: <input type="text" id="date_1" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id ="profileGroup2">
        <div class="item">
            Number2: <input type="text" id="number_2" value="2015-05-05">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            Date2: <input type="text" id="date_2" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I concatenate the Group for 1,2?

Comment: Can you explain in which condition group concentrate.

Comment: Check the answer above but there's still parts are missing. If you could make the same output as above I will mark your answer.