# How to concatenate messages or construct only in one alertbox with conditions in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-in-loop

I'm having troubled with these constructing my message in only one alertbox. I've tried my best to construct but this is all I've got. Hope someone can help me and have some explanation your answer because I'm confused about concatenating and what I'm doing it wrong.

Code:

```
$(function(){
   var len = $('#groupContainer > div').length;
   var data = [];

   for(var i=0; i < len; i++){

      var number = $('#name_' + [i + 1]);
      var date = $('#date_' + [i + 1]);
      var count = i + 1;
      var message ="";

      var a = number.map(function(){
              return this.value;
      });

      var b = date.map(function(){
              return this.value;
       });

        var newObj = {Name: a[0], Date: b[0]}
                data.push(newObj);
        }

        var message = "";
        var ErrInGroup = false;

        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
          for(var d in data[i]) {

            if(data[i].hasOwnProperty(d)) {
                 message += 'Group: ' + [i + 1] + '\n'; 
                 if(data[i][d] == "" || data[i][d] == null){
                           message += d + ' is required!\n';
                 }

                 if(d == "Date") {
                   if(data[i][d].length != 10 && data[i][d] != "") {
                       message += 'Invalid Date!\n';
                   }
                 }

             }
          }
        }

     if(message){
         alert(message);
      }

});
```

Expected Output:

[image: If all fields is empty]
[image: If Only the first field is empty]
[image: If one of the field is not empty]
[image: If there are date's that are Invalid]

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aldrin27/yzqb3jo0/)**

**Note:** The length of the Date is 10 if != to 10 then it is invalid.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but here are a few things I notice in your code. You define `message` twice - once inside the `for` loop and once inside the anonymous function passed to `number.map()`. Your final test `if (message)` is unnecessary. Since you set it to an empty string `var message = ""`, that test will always be true.

Comment: Sorry for that. I'm really confused about concatenating error message. But all I want is to have all my messages in one alertbox.

Comment: I already post this but I have an answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031166/how-to-show-message-in-for-loop-issues-in-javascript-or-using-jquery But I can't show the invalid message it only shows required. It's almost perfect.

Comment: No idea why you'd use an `alert` box. Better methods of highlighting invalid input, such as highlighting the actual invalid fields, and/or using a modal dialog popup.

Comment: @LeeTaylor it's not actually an alertbox. It is the alertbox of jeasyui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check [

```js
$(function(){

 var errorObj = {
     group: {},
     hasError: false
 };

 function errorObjMange(groupNo, type, msg) {

  errorObj.hasError = true;
  groupNo = groupNo.toString();
  if (!errorObj.group[groupNo]) {
   errorObj.group[groupNo] = {};
  }

  errorObj.group[groupNo][type] = msg;
 }

 function alertError() { 
  var priority = {
   "1": new Array(), // Invalid date
   "2": new Array(), // empty name and inavlid date
   "3": new Array(), // empty naem and empty date
   "4": new Array(), // only empty name
   "5": new Array(), // only empty DATE
  } 

  for (var groupIndex in errorObj.group) {
   var group = errorObj.group[groupIndex];
   if (!group.emptyName && !group.emptyDate && group.invalidDate) {
    priority["1"].push(groupIndex);
   }

   if (group.emptyName && !group.emptyDate && group.invalidDate) {
    priority["2"].push(groupIndex);
   }

   if (group.emptyName && group.emptyDate  && !group.invalidDate) {
    priority["3"].push(groupIndex);
   }

   if (group.emptyName && !group.emptyDat && !group.invalidDate) {
    priority["4"].push(groupIndex);
   }

   if (!group.emptyName && group.emptyDate && !group.invalidDate) { 
    priority["5"].push(groupIndex);
   }

  }

  var groupStr = "Group: ";
  var msg = '';

  if (priority["3"].length) {
   groupStr += priority["3"].toString();
   msg = groupStr + '\n'
       + 'Name is required\n'
       + 'Date is required\n'; 
  } else if (priority["2"].length) {
   groupStr += priority["2"].toString();
   msg = groupStr + '\n'
       + 'Name is required\n'
       + 'Invalid Date\n';
  }  else if (priority["4"].length || priority["5"].length) {
            msg = '';
            
            if (priority["4"].length) {
                
    groupStr = 'Group :' + priority["4"].toString(); 
    msg += groupStr + '\n'
        + 'Name is required\n'; 
            }
            
            if (priority["5"].length) {
    groupStr = 'Group :' + priority["5"].toString(); 
     msg += groupStr + '\n'
         + 'Date is required\n'; 
                
            } 
            
  }  else if (priority["1"].length) {
   groupStr += priority["1"].toString(); 
   msg = groupStr + '\n'
       + 'Invalid Date\n'; 
  }
  console.log();
  alert(msg);
 }

 // Count number of groups we have.
 var len = $('#groupContainer > div').length;
 var data = [];
 


 // For each given group
 for(var i=0; i < len; i++){

  // Get the values
     var number = $('#name_' + [i + 1]);
      var date = $('#date_' + [i + 1]); 
      var a = number.map(function(){
      return this.value;
  });

  var b = date.map(function(){
      return this.value;
  });

  var newObj = {Name: a[0], Date: b[0]};
  data.push(newObj);         
 }

 var message = "";


 var ErrInGroup = false;
 
 for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     haveErrorInGroup = false;
        
     
     for(var d in data[i])  {

         if(data[i].hasOwnProperty(d)) {
             // Its because you are doing the 
                // below line.
             //message += [i + 1] + '\n';
             
            
             if(data[i][d] == "" || data[i][d] == null){

              if (d == 'Name') {
               errorObjMange((i+1), 'emptyName', (d + ' is required!\n'));
              }

              if (d == 'Date') {
               errorObjMange((i+1), 'emptyDate', (d + ' is required!\n'));
              }
             }
           
            if(d == "Date" && !(data[i][d] == "" || data[i][d] == null))  {
                 if(!(new Date(data[i][d]))
                    || !(/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/.test(data[i][d].trim()))) {
                    message += 'Invalid Date!\n';
                 errorObjMange((i+1), 'invalidDate',  'Invalid Date!\n');
                                             
                }
            } 
        }
    }

}

if(errorObj.hasError){ 
 alertError();
    //console.log(errorObj);
}
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="groupContainer">
    <div id ="profileGroup1">
        <div class="item">
            Name1: <input type="text" id="name_1" value="asdf">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
           Date1: <input type="text" id="date_1" value="01/50/48">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id ="profileGroup2">
        <div class="item">
            Number2: <input type="text" id="name_2" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            Date2: <input type="text" id="date_2" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I will check this first. Tnx.

Comment: Almost there bro. Delete all the records. It should be showing this. http://i.stack.imgur.com/PDQow.png

Comment: Can you refer to this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031166/how-to-show-message-in-for-loop-issues-in-javascript-or-using-jquery. And add the invalid date?

Comment: you mean when date is invalid no need to display the date required ?

Comment: No if the date field is empty it should show required but if date is not empty and the length is not equal to 22 it will show invalid date rather than required message.

Comment: Why does it shows error in Group1,2? If group 1 field is not empty. The error must show Group2 Name is required Date is required.

Comment: Yes that's fine for me. If it gives me the correct output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92001/discussion-between-dinesh-patra-and-aldrin27).

Comment: Sorry chat is blocked in my office.

Comment: okay can we combine both empty date and invalid date to same type error as 'Valid date reqired' ?

Comment: No. The invalid type must be in else.

Comment: The group length is dynamic. And it will change from time to time.

Comment: There's still one problem. If all the fields are filled it should not alert the alertbox

Comment: Your code is working just as expected in validations. But if I give a valid date it shows the 1 1 2 2. And Try to change first the length of date in 10. Because the length of 01/02/2015 is 10

Comment: can you mention a valid date example, so that i can correct ?

Comment: 10/20/2015 that's valid

Comment: But its length is not 22, so its not a valid date.

Comment: Sorry. It's my fault on my end. I change the question to a valid date to 10.

Comment: for all correct its printing message, which you have used: message += [i + 1] + '\n';

One more thing for ate validation use  if(!(new Date(data[i][d]))) { 
I have updated answer please check.

Comment: Please see http://jsfiddle.net/dineshpatra28/o9tzt59u/1/ line number 118 under js section and also read my previous comment.

Thank you.

Comment: What should I do to remove `message += [i + 1] + '\n'`?

Comment: I have commented that line and removed the else of alert:
http://jsfiddle.net/dineshpatra28/o9tzt59u/2/ .Please check now. Plesae do validation as I have mentioned in previous comment, not using length == 10

Comment: Okay I will use that. But why does `new Date` don't trigger if it's not a valid date?

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/aldrin27/o9tzt59u/3/. And I will accept now your answer.

Comment: I will get back to you after  hour. Going office.

Comment: Okay. My expected output is almost there.

Comment: Please check the fddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dineshpatra28/o9tzt59u/4/

Here I have added regx for validation:  if(!(new Date(data[i][d]))
                        || !(/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/.test(data[i][d].trim()))) { 

The previously It was noy working because javascript was taking 1234 as year.

Comment: One last error. Then it will all be answered. If Name is empty in group 1 and Date is empty in group 2. The error message shall be Group 1: is required Group 2: is required. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aldrin27/o9tzt59u/5/

Comment: No. It should be Group1 : Name is required. then new line Group2: Date. Sorry for being noob. Because i'm still confused about this.

Comment: Its okay. By the way I am also learning: Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/dineshpatra28/o9tzt59u/7/